# Pandas rearrange and interpolate time-series based with datetime index

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, pandas-resample

I have a recurrent problem that I solve inelegantly every-time, and I am unable to find a good way to do it.
Let's say I have a dataframe with datetime in index, spanning every 3 hours (df1). I have another dataframe spanning every day (df2).

I want to do 2 things:

- Resample the df1 to span everyday instead of every 3h, by calculating a mean of each 3h periods over a day.
- Interpolate df2 for any day that would be missing, and add that day where it belongs.

Issues: I use for loops (and want to avoid that) and the resampling of missing days is incomplete (can only attribute 1 value).

This is how I was doing it:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from datetime import *

# Create df1
rng = pd.date_range('2000-01-01', periods=365*(24/3), freq='3H')
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Val': np.random.randn(len(rng)) }, index = rng)

# Create df2 and drop a few rows
rng2 = pd.date_range('2000-01-01', periods=365, freq='D')
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Val': np.random.randn(len(rng2)) },index = rng2)
df2 = df2.drop([datetime(2000,1,5),datetime(2000,1,24)])

# Create reference timelist 
date_list = [datetime(2000,1,1) + timedelta(days=x) for x in range(365)]


# Calculate the daily mean of df1:
# We create an array hosting the resampled values of df1
arr = []
c = 1

# Loop that appends the array everytime we hit a new day, and calculate a mean of the day that passed
for i in range(1,len(df1)):

    if c < 365 and df1.index[i] == date_list[c]:
        arr.append(np.mean(df1[i-8:i])[0])
        c = c + 1

# Calculate the last value of the array
arr.append(np.mean(df1[i-7:i+1])[0])

# Create a new dataframe hosting the daily values from df1
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'Val': arr}, index = rng2)


# Replace missing days in df2
df2 = df2.reindex(date_list, fill_value=0)
df2 = df2.resample('D').interpolate(method='linear') # but this does not work
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are two simple fixes for both these issues; you just need to update your use of `resample` for both.

#### First point: just resample

Your first point is precisely a case of downsampling with `resample`.  You can replace your whole creation of `df3` with:

```
df1.resample('D').mean()
```

This is going to average all the 3 hour periods for each day.  For confirmation, we can check that your results are the same as what I am proposing:

```
>>> all(df1.resample('D').mean().round(8) == df3.round(8))
True
```

Note that I have to round because there are floating point errors between your code and `resample`; but they are extremely close.

#### Second point: don't reindex first

When you interpolate in the second case to fill the missing days, you want to still have the missing days to fill!  AKA, if you `reindex` first and fill the value with `0`, the interpolation "fails" because it doesn't find anything to interpolate.  So if I get your issue correctly, you just want to remove the `reindex` line:

```
# df2 = df2.reindex(date_list, fill_value=0)
df2 = df2.resample('D').interpolate(method='linear')
```

So if you start with `df2` like this:

```
>>> df.head(10)
                 Val
2000-01-01  0.235151
2000-01-02  1.279017
2000-01-03 -1.267074
2000-01-04 -0.270182 # the fifth is missing
2000-01-06  0.382649
2000-01-07  0.120253
2000-01-08 -0.223690
2000-01-09  1.379003
2000-01-10 -0.477681
2000-01-11  0.619466
```

You end with this:

```
>>> df2.head(10)
                 Val
2000-01-01  0.235151
2000-01-02  1.279017
2000-01-03 -1.267074
2000-01-04 -0.270182
2000-01-05  0.056233 # the fifth is here, halfway between 4th and 6th
2000-01-06  0.382649
2000-01-07  0.120253
2000-01-08 -0.223690
2000-01-09  1.379003
2000-01-10 -0.477681
```

Comment: Thank you for those great examples !